# VB.NET - Put a form in a panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I wanna to put all controls of a determinated form in a panel. No problem so far, however the elements added to the panel are resized. Suppose that the panel is 800x600 in size and the module containing the controls that I want to add to the panel is the same size, i.e. 800x600. The controls are automatically resized despite the fact that autosize is disabled both on the panel and in the module itself. I wrote a function that switch controls of a form to another.

Sub SwitchPanel(ByVal FormToShow As Form)

```
FormToShow.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
FormToShow.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)

FormToShow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
Home.GunaPanel.Controls.Clear()
FormToShow.TopLevel = False
Home.GunaPanel.Controls.Add(FormToShow)
FormToShow.Show()
Home.GunaPanel.Show()
FormToShow.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
FormToShow.AutoSize = False

End Sub
```

Thanks! Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Ive only used VB like twice in my life but I know in C# you can use the size property to give it a min/max size. If both of those are the same then the size cant change. Tedious to have to set that on every control but maybe itll work.

Comment: Set both Forms' `AutoScaleMode = Dpi`, set explicitly the font of all controls in the *demoted* Form to a specific Font (don't let the Controls inherit the Font from the Parent). Set `FormToShow.FormBorderStyle = None`. How `FormToShow.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` affects the child Controls depends on the Controls Dock mode or Anchor style. You could use a TableLayoutPanel to better manage their layout. Anyway, I suggest to build a UserControl instead.

Comment: Set `AutoScaleMode = Dpi` in the designer, then fix/restore any *displacement* that this may cause.